# Adding a Wait or Delay to Java

Tags: java, wait, sleep

So I have some Java code that once it has ran through that part, I want it wait/delay for some amount of time. Here is the code I have:

```
Trajectory exampleTrajectory =
        TrajectoryGenerator.generateTrajectory(trajectory);
        TimeUnits.Second.sleep(10)
```

I have tried using TimeUnits.Second.sleep(10) but I keep getting an error saying that it cannot be resolved.

Comment: [mcve] please .. including imports ..

Comment: Should be `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
TimeUnits.Second.sleep(10)
```

It should be:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
```

Complete working example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
class Main { 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("a");

    try {
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10); // 10 second delay
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    
    System.out.println("b");
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's [Thread.sleep(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) that you can use to **block** the current thread.

Secondly, you can utilize [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)  to **schedule** the task for later, **not blocking** the current thread.